# Convert a VS Setup Project Custom Action to InstallShield Project Custom Action

Tags: visual-studio, installshield

I have a standard visual studio setup project that I am converting to an InstallShield LE project.

I have the following custom action under CustomActions-Install-PrimaryOutputFromMyProject(Active) - CustomActionData - **/sectionName="userSettings/SSE.My.MySettings" /provName="DPAPIProtection"**

How do I recreate this custom action in InstallShield?

Here is the code in my installer class all it does is protect some of the sections of the app.config file:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Configuration.Install
Imports System.Configuration

'// This file encrypts the app.config file
Public Class CustomInstaller
    Inherits Installer
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()

        'This call is required by the Component Designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        'Add initialization code after the call to InitializeComponent

    End Sub
    Public Overrides Sub Install(ByVal stateSaver As System.Collections.IDictionary)
        MyBase.Install(stateSaver)

        'get Configuration section 
        'name from custom action parameter
        Dim sectionName As String = Me.Context.Parameters("sectionName")

        'get Protected Configuration Provider 
        'name from custom action parameter
        Dim provName As String = Me.Context.Parameters("provName")

        ' get the exe path from the default context parameters
        Dim exeFilePath As String = Me.Context.Parameters("assemblypath")

        'encrypt the configuration section
        ProtectSection(sectionName, provName, exeFilePath)
    End Sub
    Private Sub ProtectSection(ByVal sectionName As String, ByVal provName As String, ByVal exeFilePath As String)
        Dim config As Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exeFilePath)
        Dim section As ConfigurationSection = config.GetSection(sectionName)

        If Not section.SectionInformation.IsProtected Then
            'Protecting the specified section with the specified provider
            section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(provName)
        End If
        section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = True
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read my augmenting series:

[Augmenting InstallShield using Windows Installer XML - Certificates](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2011/01/augmenting-installshield-using-windows.html)

[Augmenting InstallShield using Windows Installer XML - Windows Services](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2011/01/augmenting-installshield-using-windows_19.html)

Basically I would do it this way:

1) Refactor the code in your InstallerClass ( InstallUtil ) custom action into a WiX DTF custom action.  This step is technically optional but if you know all the horrible things associated with InstallUtil you'd do it to.

2) Author a WiX merge module to consume the DLL as a custom action and sequence it in the ModuleExecuteSequence table.

3) Add the merge module to your InstallShield LE project.

Note: InstallShield 2010LE is basically stripped-down-featureset-ware.  You can use it for upgrade pricing of $1500 to InstallShield Professional edition.  If you can justify this, I would do it.  The reality is LE has some capabilities and I can think of some creative ways of augmenting it but it's far easier to do in normal InstallShield.

Comment: thanks for your help, originally most of that went way over my head.  I've been googling away for the past few days and I now have a better understanding of what you are suggesting.  I have added my code to the original post, can you shed some more light on the situation after looking at it?

Comment: You might want to look at your VDPROJ generated MSI using ORCA and get a feel for the underlying table data that implements your CA.  From there you'll have to figure out how to do it in InstallShield.

Comment: This is all getting very complicated, at least to me anyway.  All I want to do is protect the app.config file.  It seems it may be easier to just find another way of protecting it or go back to using the windows setup project instead of installshield.  Very frustrating.

Comment: Well, I could probably teach you how to do it in about an hour.  There's just a lot involved when it comes to serializing and deserialing a dictionary using the CustomActionData pattern.  It's difficult to explain in all by answering a single question.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, I understand completely.  My frustration was certainly not directed at you, I'm just disappointed as it was an easy process to protect the app.config in a VS setup project but much more difficult in installshield and I really liked using the installshield.

Comment: When you say "protect" what I think you are saying is that you want to read certain elements / attributes into propeties, replace the app.config with the new version and then apply those elements and attributes back.  Correct?  If so, I could show you how to do that using native InstallShield functionality without writing any custom actions.  And yes, it's a pain that you have to do that.  When Microsoft invented the default file versioning rules ( i.e. userdata doesn't get overwritten ) they clearly didn't have XML in mind.

Comment: All I need to be able to do is to encrypt the section of the app.config file that contains my database connection strings when my app is installed.  If I don't encrypt the connection string then the end user can simply open the file and get the database connection username and password.

Comment: A lot of people suggest moving that type of behavior out of the installer and into the "first run" of the application.  Would that work for you?  Simplifies the install alot.  Otherwise if I did this in InstallShield ( perhaps not LE ) I would write a custom action that gets the properties from the dialog and calculates the encrypted connection string  then I would use InstallShield XML changes to actually apply the encrypted property to the XML file.

Comment: I did not want to use a first run scenario because the user who does the first run may not have admin privileges and cannot modify the app.config file as the app wont be under elevated permissions.  In turn I don't want the installer doing a first run because he wont know the additional first run details that the user will. I would prefer to get the properties from a dialogue and protect but  Unfortunately I don't think LE allows me to use XML changes.

Comment: WiX has XML changes and if you package them up into a merge module InstallShield can consume it.

Comment: OKay, I have managed to download and install wix and create a merge module project, Im stuck on what to do next, are there any examples for applying the encryption to the property of the app.config file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4528/discussion-between-christopher-painter-and-reafidy)

Comment: Okay so this just became to difficult, I'm going to mark this as the answer because I am assuming it will work. In reality I am going to have to find another way.

Answer (score 1):

InstallShield doesn't really support project output custom actions. This is because Windows Installer uses EXE and DLL custom actions as specific files, not as a dynamic outputs.

Also, InstallShield LE doesn't support DLL custom actions. So you can use only an EXE, VBScript or JScript.

Since you used CustomActionData, I'm guessing your project output is a DLL. You cannot create a DLL custom action in InstallShield LE.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I'm not sure what you mean because I have definitely added a project output.

Comment: I was using Solution Explorer. Forgot the project assistant supported project outputs. I updated my answer.

Comment: Even if InstallShield didn't support project references, it would be trivial to modify the .isproj file to inject an msbuild copy task to bring the file over to a relative path location.